# How can I create a boxplot in R, by column?

Tags: r, statistics, boxplot

```
    year month t.max t.min frost rain    NA
25  1961     1   6.1   0.5    13  320  29.2
26  1961     2   9.9   3.8     1  210  55.7
27  1961     3  13.1   3.3     2  390 139.6
28  1961     4  13.9   5.8     0  411  77.2
29  1961     5  15.1   5.4     3   69 188.9
30  1961     6  19.8   8.7     0   84 223.6
31  1961     7  19.3  10.3     0  281 157.4
32  1961     8  19.9  10.8     0  413 184.0
33  1961     9  19.7  10.2     0  152 129.5
34  1961    10  14.5   6.6     1  260 110.8
35  1961    11   9.2   2.7     6  238  60.0
36  1961    12   4.9  -1.2    19  429  48.1
37  1962     1   7.4   0.5     8  290  72.0
38  1962     2   7.4   1.1    10   66  63.1
39  1962     3   6.4  -1.7    21  131  98.5
40  1962     4  11.5   3.1     3  215 130.4
41  1962     5  14.0   5.7     2  143 132.3
42  1962     6  18.5   7.8     2  414 194.6
43  1962     7  18.9  10.3     0  108 114.9
44  1962     8  18.3  10.0     0  469 130.0
45  1962     9  16.4   8.6     0  489 108.9
46  1962    10  14.1   5.8     2  486  90.2
47  1962    11   8.3   2.1     7  112  37.4
48  1962    12   4.5  -2.6    20  188  43.7
```

I have the following data and I want to create 12 boxplots (one for each month) of the variable t.max . My problem is there is more than one of each month and I don't know how to tell R I want a boxplot for month 1, 2, ...etc?
Thanks

Comment: `boxplot(t.max ~ month, data=dat)` I think.

Comment: "more than one of each month" is not a problem, you need multiple observations per month for a boxplot to be meaningful.